# Cheapest option to get a bike for a week Amsterdam

Tags: transportation, bicycles, amsterdam, rental

Amsterdam is bike city. Almost every local has a bike, and I remember there are quite a few places where you can rent one. But - rentals are probably expensive ([this answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/36989/33321) says 15 EUR / 24h); and I know that you can buy a simple, second-hand bike for 50-60 EUR (eg. on marktplaats.nl). Of course, if you buy a bike there might be something wrong with it, there's no insurance, etc. etc.

So, for a stay of 8 days, is it better to rent or to just buy a bike? And - are there any other alternatives?

PS - I'll only be riding my bike within the city and never out into the country.

Comment: I wouldn't want to go _anywhere_ on a bike that someone is willing to sell for 60 euro. It would be hit-and-miss if it was rideable at all.

Comment: Do you still have OV chip card?

Comment: Or you can try to use https://hello-bike.net/

Comment: Also to consider: If you rent a bike you have a place to go to in case something breaks

Comment: @EugenMartynov: Yes :-)

Comment: @nohillside: But then I can't just go to any bike shop I'm next to...

Comment: @HenningMakholm: I rode such a bike for nearly 2 years. Now, it's true, I did have to install a back light and a bell which were kind of broken, and a few months later a tire, but still. We're talking plain, old, omafiets here.

Comment: The bike shop next door may need a day or two to fix it. With a rental you would just get a replacement and ride on.

Comment: @nohillside: But I would need to get my bike to the rental place, which can be quite a challenge if your bike breaks down while you're using it.

Comment: Do you really want to spend perhaps an entire day of your stay in Amsterdam to drive around and look at different used bikes in the hope to find a good and cheap deal? If you want to make a bargain when buying a used bike, and that is likely possible, you must at least expect to spend some time to look at different offers.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo: No, I don't expect to go arond town looking for deals, I was hoping for another idea. And, in fact, it seems I've gotten at least one...

Answer (score 7):

I know someone who bought bikes for a whole family (and some friends) from marktplaats.nl and after their holiday sold them for more than he paid. Did cost him some weeks.

I'd say for one week, without a friend to buy before you come and sell after you left, renting is likely the easiest cheap option. Railway station bike sheds often have good rates.
[This a site that compares bike rental companies.](https://www.huren.nl/c135/fietsen/amsterdam) Not all companies are included, as far as I could see with a quick look on a category I know a company near Amsterdam, but there are enough there for you to get a good feel for the market.

[Or see ahead of time if you can get an OV fiets pas.](https://www.ns.nl/en/door-to-door/ov-fiets/purchase-a-season-ticket-online.html) (Card to rent OV bikes with, usually a personal OV card connected to a Dutch bank account.)
I checked and it is indeed [impossible to rent such a bike without a OV chip card.](https://community.ns.nl/ov-fiets-48/ov-fiets-zonder-ov-chipkaart-46759)
The problem with these cards is that you need to pay with a Dutch bank account (and you pay after the fact, so they want to be sure you can use your bank account for it.) No option to pay cash or by card.